# Asp.Net load data by button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple list view where I'm loading my data.
Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        IList<Product> products;

        using (ISession session = NHibernateSession.OpenSession())  // Open a session to conect to the database
        {
            products = session.Query<Product>().ToList(); //  Querying to get all the books
        }

        return View(products);
    }
}
```

View is a simple list view from template.
Now, I need to load data to list view just after button click.
So as I understand I need to render partial view.
I've add this to view:

```html
<button id="Load">Load data</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("LoadData", "Home")';
    $('#Load').click(function() {
      var keyWord = $('#Keyword').val();
      $('#result').load(url);
    })
    </script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And add controller action:

```
public ActionResult LoadData()
{
    // here will be model creation and passing view
    return PartialView();
}
```

But controller action doesn't get called.
What should I do?

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Now I that I have "$ is not defined", but I'v include JQuery script in layout.cshtml

Comment: Then its not being loaded correctly or in the wrong order, and your script should be immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, or wrapped in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: also, button by default type is "submit" for ajax please specify button type "button" (in case page is being submitted).

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is now I would do it.

We create an action method which return JSON on http gets

```
public class SomeController : Controller

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoadData()
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateSession.OpenSession())  // Open a session to conect to the database
        {
            products = session.Query<Product>().ToList(); //  Querying to get all the books
        }

        return Json(new {data=product},
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Inside your view we do a ajax request to get the data by calling LoadData

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'SomeController/LoadData',
  success: function (data) {
    //Render data to view maybe using jquery etc                                
  },
  error: function(data) {
    //Notify user of error
  }
});
```

Hope this helps man